# Session automatically logout out while doing payment how to stop session logout

Tags: php, session

Session automatically logout. while doing payment how to stop session logout in php

Comment: That'll depend on how your sessions are configured, but the default time should be at least a couple of hours; if sessions are going away during a payment process (which should take minutes, at most) I'd be looking at other sources for the problem.

Comment: most probably your time sessions are in minutes, it should be at least a couple of hours. Please add your code so we can look into it.